# Converting Dates in different format (objects) in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-dateutil

I am new here, I apologize if the layout is not typical.

I have a large csv with around 150,000 rows. The Date column alternates between two formats, but it always increases in increments of 10 minutes.

First 2001-02-08 2:30:00 AM -- %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p

Second 01/13/08 00:20:00 -- %y/%d/%m %H:%M:%

I have a bunch of ways, one is to parse as I read_csv and second is to use pd.to_dateime. But I keep getting an erroneous output.

The attached picture is the output from

```
df1['Test'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'],yearfirst=True)
```

the year in the output should not be 2008

[image: Output]

[Format1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVgke.png)
[Fortmat2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS3qZ.png)

Comment: Please add a typical sample of the Date column with both formats.

Comment: @DyZ i attached two screen shots form the oringal file. Thanks

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of either code or data as we cannot copy them, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the dates both ways and combine the results:

```
df1['Test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], format="%y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S", 
                                    errors='coerce')\
                .combine_first(pd.to_datetime(df['A']))
```

The call to the first `to_datetime` with the option `errors='coerce'` will produce a `NaT` ("not-a-time") if the date is in the wrong format. Those `NaT`s will be filled by the values produced by the second call to `to_datetime`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I had like 30 tabs open on how to do this.

I ran it without the combine and it worked!

df1['Test'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format="%y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S", errors='coerce')